# svn: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output

Tags: svn, version-control

Hi I'm trying to get the post-commit hook to update the dev site instead of having to do it manually everytime a team member commits changes.

I am running under centos with subversion 1.8

1) I compiled in c the autoupdate executable and it works fine when i call it from the shell as root
2) I call the autoupdate executable in post-commit which I chmod +x
here is the content of the post commit:

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/www/repos/fundica_new/autoupdate/autoupdate
```

3) executing the post-commit hook through shell : bash post-commit also updates with no errors

Note: when I commit changes the "commit itsefl succeeds but not the post comit hook
Here is my error

```
At revision: 1521
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svn: E155004: Run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
svn: E155004: Working copy '/var/www/vhosts/s15399220.onlinehome-server.com/dev' locked
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: E200031: Additional errors:
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
```

Comment: Does the user account under which your Subversion server runs have full control over `/var/www/vhosts/s15399220.onlinehome-server.com/dev`?

Comment: It seems to me that something's wrong with your working copy at `/var/www/vhosts/s15399220.onlinehome-server.com/dev`. If you run the hook script again now from the shell, will that work? (I doubt that)

Comment: When I run the post-commit hook manually i.e(bash post-commit) it runs no problem ... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I am running under AIX 6.1 on PowerPC with Subversion 1.8.5 (r1542147)

Add variable LANG and cleanup statement.

```
    export LANG=${your_language_environment}  ## LANG=en_US 
    svn cleanup ${working_copy_directory} --username ${username} --password ${password} 
    svn update ${working_copy_directory} --parent --username ${username} --password ${password}
```

Good luck.